# findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: gets data from Parse, but data only exists inside the block

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, parse-platform

I made the following test class to try out retrieving data from Parse:

```
-(void)retrieveDataFromParse
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestObject"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){
            for (PFObject *object in objects){
                NSString *nameFromObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"Name"]];
                NSString *dateFromObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object createdAt]];
                NSString *scoreFromObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"Score"]];
                [self addNewScore:scoreFromObject andDate:dateFromObject forUserName:nameFromObject];
                NSLog(@"The dictionary is %@", self.scoreDictionary); //<-- here it works printing out the whole dictionary
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"The dictionary is %@", self.scoreDictionary); //<- but after the block is called, here the dictionary is again empty...
}
```

Per the commented section inside the code, when I print `self.scoreDictionary` inside the code, it works out fine, and I see my entire dictionary as it incrementally gets filled.  However, after the block ends, when I print the dictionary again, it is now empty.  I double checked with the query API docs, but I still am unsure what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The last `NSLog(@"The dictionary is %@", self.scoreDictionary)` statement does not actually execute after the block completes. It executes after the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` method returns. `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` presumably runs something in a separate thread, and your block may not actually execute at all until some length of time after that last NSLog statement. Graphically, something like this is probably happening:

```
Thread 1 
--------
retriveDataFromParse called
invoke findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock queues up work on another thread
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock returns immediately      |
NSLog statement - self.scoreDictionary not yet updated    |
retriveDataFromParse returns                              |
.                                                         V
.                       Thread 2, starting X milliseconds later
.                       --------
.                       findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock does some work
.                       your block is called
.                       for-loop in your block
.                       Now self.scoreDictionary has some data
.                       NSLog statement inside your block
```

You probably want to think about, **what do you want to do with your scoreDictionary data after you have retrieved it**? For example, do you want to update the UI, call some other method, etc.? You will want to do this *inside* your block, at which point you know the data has been successfully retrieved. For example, if you had a table view you wanted to reload, you could do this:

```
for (PFObject *object in objects){
    ....
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self updateMyUserInterfaceOrSomething];
});
```

Note the `dispatch_async` - if the work you need to do after updating your data involves changing the UI, you'll want that to run on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the very helpful illustration showing the threads!

Answer (score 0):

The last `NSLog(@"The dictionary is %@", self.scoreDictionary)` is executed before the completion block executes. By the time, `self.scoreDictionary` will be empty for sure.

Besides, the completion block will be executed on main thread. You can refer to the following link.

https://parse.com/questions/what-thread-does-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-complete-on