# Return a value within findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In my `queryForTable` method, I'm trying to return a query within `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` because my results rely something inside the block, but it results in error:

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'PFQuery *(^)(NSArray *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'PFArrayResultBlock' (aka 'void (^)(NSArray *__strong, NSError *__strong)')
```

I'm doing this because I need to compare `ObjectID` with Object Pointer, which is not allowed in Parse.com, so I have to fetch all the `ObjectIDs` from the Object Pointers and save them in an array within the block, and use the array to make another query, then return the query.

But the point is I can't return a query within the block, and the query relies the results within the block.

What is the correct way to achieve this?  Thanks.

edited (with codes provided):

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
        PFQuery *isFollowingQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];
        [isFollowingQuery whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:self.User];
        [isFollowingQuery whereKey:@"activity" equalTo:@"follow"];
        [isFollowingQuery includeKey:@"toUser"]; //toUser is a user pointer

        [isFollowingQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            PFQuery *followingUsers = [PFUser query];
            [followingUsers whereKey:@"objectID" containedIn:objects];

            return followingUsers;
        }];
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? There might be a way to accomplish this without two separate queries, but it is difficult to understand exactly what you are doing from this description.

Comment: Also, using `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` inside of `queryForTable` will not work. `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous method. You really do not want to rely on a query within `queryForTable`.

Comment: hi @Alex, i have added my code, basically what i'm trying to achieve is just to show the list of users the current user is following in the table.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that you want to query the Users table for a list of users that the current user is following?  Parse won't let you query the Users table from the client for any records other than the current user.  I think you are probably going to need a cloud code method that uses the master key to do what you want.

Comment: Further reading at: [findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: gets data from Parse but data only exists inside the block](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18021880)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want a list of `User` objects that the current user is following. You already have that after your first query, since you used `includeKey` on `toUser`.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable { 
    PFQuery *isFollowingQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];
    [isFollowingQuery whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:self.User];
    [isFollowingQuery whereKey:@"activity" equalTo:@"follow"];
    [isFollowingQuery includeKey:@"toUser"]; //toUser is a user pointer
    return isFollowingQuery;
}
```

Now, this is the correct query to return from queryForTable.

Then, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you get the User object you want to display:

```
PFUser *user = [object objectForKey:@"toUser"];
```

Remember that in the special `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the `PFQueryTableViewController` you also get the object for the current row.

Then you can get the value(s) you want from the user object. **All inn cellForRowAtIndexPath**

Comment: Just noticed from the code I copied that this is the queryForTable method. Then this will not work. The code would work fine any other place, but not in queryForTable (as you're only supposed to return a query, not the list of users). Let me think on this a little

Comment: simplest and straightforward solution, thx!