# Trying to add multiple GeoPoints to mapView from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, parse-platform

I'm performing a query to get several GeoPoints along with titles and subtitles for annotations. The query is downloading the data from parse in the block and I can log self.locations; however, when I try to log/use self.locations in viewDidLoad it returns null. What am I missing here?

Below is my code

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface PeopleMoverMap : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) double userLat;
@property (nonatomic) double userLong;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *locations;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *lats;
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *lngs;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

-(void)retrieveLocations;

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "PeopleMoverMap.h"
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

@interface PeopleMoverMap ()

@end

@implementation PeopleMoverMap


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveLocations)];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



    // Add multiple pins


    for (NSDictionary *location in self.locations) {
        PFGeoPoint *tempGeo = location[@"GeoPoint"];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tempGeo.latitude, tempGeo.longitude);
        MapAnnotation *annotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.coordinate = annotationCoordinate;
//        annotation.title = location[@"Name"];
//        annotation.subtitle = location[@"Place"];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    }

    // Get user coordinates
    self.userLat = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    self.userLong = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"%f:%f", self.userLat, self.userLong);

    // Initialize and set arrays
    self.lats = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.lngs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self.lats addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.userLat]];
    [self.lngs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.userLong]];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in self.locations) {
        PFGeoPoint *tempGeo = dict[@"GeoPoint"];
        [self.lats addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tempGeo.latitude]];
        [self.lngs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:tempGeo.longitude]];
    }

    // Sort numbers in arrays
    [self.lats sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    [self.lngs sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    // Get smalles/biggest coordinates
    double smallestLat = [self.lats[0] doubleValue];
    double smallestLng = [self.lngs[0] doubleValue];
    double biggestLat = [[self.lats lastObject] doubleValue];
    double biggestLng = [[self.lngs lastObject] doubleValue];

    // Get Center Point and Span
    CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationsCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((biggestLat + smallestLat) / 2, (biggestLng + smallestLng) / 2);
    MKCoordinateSpan annotationsSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake((biggestLat - smallestLat) * 1.75, (biggestLng - smallestLng) * 1.75);

    // Create and set Region
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(annotationsCenter, annotationsSpan);
    [self.mapView setRegion:region];
}

-(void)retrieveLocations
{
    PFQuery *retrievePMLocations = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"peopleMoverLocations"];
    [retrievePMLocations orderByAscending:@"Name"];
    [retrievePMLocations findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.locations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:selector method instead. In the selector method, assign the results to the array AND also move the code to add pins there. Right now even though your code in retrieveLocations runs in a block, the rest of the ViewDidLoad code is called immediately instead of after block completion.

Related question: [findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: gets data from Parse, but data only exists inside the block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021880/findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-gets-data-from-parse-but-data-only-exists-ins)

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of understanding how async code works.

Calling your `retrieveLocations` method is like putting eggs on to cook, it starts them cooking then goes onto the next step.

If you straight away try to use the eggs without waiting for them to cook, you'll get messy real quick. The same with your code... you might get lucky depending on your code, where sometimes it has finished "cooking" (async code finished running) by the time your other code is hit, but you are much better off doing it properly.

In your case, start the async process and prepare the rest of your UI with a "loading..." animation or equivalent. Move the rest of the code that triggers an update of the UI into the completion block of your async code, as that code is only actually run once it has finished getting the data.