# Parse: Array loses data outside of query

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform

I am using the following code in viewDidLoad to fill an array and log the count:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        for (Friends *currentFriend in objects) {
            _relation = currentFriend.friendsRelation;
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _query = [_relation query];
            _array = [_query findObjects];
            _array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_array];
        });
    }];
NSLog(@"count: %lu", [_array2 count]);
```

This logs count: 0 But, when I set numberOfRowsInSection to 1 and put the follwing code in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it logs count: 1. How come _array2's count is losing it's value outside of the for loop?

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        for (Friends *currentFriend in objects) {
            _relation = currentFriend.friendsRelation;
            _query = [_relation query];
            _array = [_query findObjects];
            _array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_array];
            NSLog(@"count: %lu", [_array2 count]);
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _query = [_relation query];
            _array = [_query findObjects];
            _array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_array];
            _friend = [_array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.usernameLabel.text = [_friend  objectForKey:@"user"];
            cell.chosenText.text = [_friend objectForKey:@"text"];
        });
    }];
```

I implemented the solution from here, but it still gives the same result: [findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: gets data from Parse, but data only exists inside the block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021880/findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-gets-data-from-parse-but-data-only-exists-ins)

Comment: You need to show where you're doing the log.

Comment: Oops forgot that, edited it in.

Comment: Your first log is 0 because it will log immediately, before the asynchronous method, findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock get the data. That's the way async methods work. The array isn't losing anything, you're just logging it before it is created.

Comment: Alright, how do I make it so I can log the count outside of it?

Comment: Your logic needs to be structured in such a way that you don't use _array2 until it is created. You can use a completion block, or you could use a delegate protocol, where you would call the delegate method at the end of the dispatch_async block.

Comment: How do I add a completion block to `[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock]`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the data (I assume you want to do more than log it)? If you're using the array to populate a table view, just call reloadData from the end of the dispatch_async block.

Comment: I'm trying to use it for the row count in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: I added the reload and it works. Thanks. You should move it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not 'losing data' at all. Rather, your log statement is getting called *before* your query finished.

It's important to understand that often (if not nearly always) code enclosed in a block will be run at an indeterminate time, possibly on a different thread. It's common for APIs to save the block you pass in, perform work on a background thread, and then execute that block at a later time.

Put another way, think of the block of code that you pass in as a variable. **The method you're calling can execute it whenever it wants to** (or never). It then becomes obvious that your program flow will continue to your log statement before that block is executed.

A simple design pattern is including code in your block to refresh the view which consumes your data.

In this case, a simple `[self.tableView reloadData];` should suffice. However, since your block will be executed on an indeterminate thread (like a background thread), make sure you dispatch to the main thread for this UI-related refresh!